# Why doesn't passing Nil to foldLeft work?

Tags: scala, type-inference, fold

When I build a list using `foldLeft` I often get annoyed at having to explicitly type the injected parameter and wish I could just use `Nil' instead - here's a contrived example:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).foldLeft(List[Int]())((x,y) =>  y :: x)
res17: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1)

scala> List(1,2,3).foldLeft(Nil)((x, y) => y :: x)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
              List(1,2,3).foldLeft(Nil)((x,y) =>  y :: x)
```

This isn't so bad with a `List[Int]` but as soon as you start using lists of your own classes, which are almost certainly going to have longer names, or even lists of tuples or other containers, so there are multiple class names you need to specify, it gets horrendous:

```
list.foldLeft(List.empty[(SomethingClass, SomethingElseClass)]) { (x,y) => y :: x }
```

I'm guessing that the reason it doesn't work is that whereas with something like `5 :: Nil` the compiler can infer the type of the empty list to be `List[Int]`, but when `Nil` is passed as a parameter to `foldLeft` it doesn't have enough information to do so, and by the time it gets round to being used its type is set. But - is it really true that it couldn't? Could it not infer the type from the return type of the function passed as the second argument?

And if not, is there some neater idiom I just don't know about?

Comment: It is lamentable that Scala cannot infer the type for these kinds of situations. Let's hope that this is amended in the future.

Comment: It shouldn't be too much of a problem in practice. If you're just dealing with a some specific classes, either make a type alias at the top `type S = (SomethingClass, SomethingElseClass)` or `val nil = List.empty[(SomethingClass, SomethingElseClass)]`. If you're writing a generic method, your types will already have short aliases such as `T` and `U`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Scalas type inference engine works from left to right - therefore scalac can not infer the correct type for the first parameter list of foldLeft. You have to give the compiler a hint what type to use. Instead of using `List[TYPE]()` you can use `List.empty[TYPE]`:

```
(List(1,2,3) foldLeft List.empty[Int]) { (x,y) =>  y :: x }
(List.empty[Int] /: List(1, 2, 3)) { (x,y) => y :: x }
```

Comment: So there's no shorter way around this? When it's eg a list of tuples it starts to look ridiculous: `list.foldLeft(List.empty[(SomethingClass, SomethingElseClass)]) { (x,y) => y :: x }`. It takes up a whole line and obscures the meaning of what you're actually trying to do!

Comment: @Russell: No, there is no shorter way. The only thing you can do is to define a type alias which is useful when you have multiple occurrences of the "long" type.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers, given that I can't accept both I will accept one and upvote the other.

Answer (score 12):

Scala's type inference works one parameter block at a time.  `Nil` without any other context has no particular type, so the most restrictive type possible (`Nothing`) is chosen.

It also can't infer the return type of the function because the return type depends on the type of `Nil`.  Getting out of that sort of circularity is tricky in general (if you don't specify what you mean).

There are a few tricks that you can apply, though, to make things less cumbersome.

First, the type signature of `fold` has only the type of the collection, so if you can use that sort of fold, you can get around the problem.  For example, you could write your own reverse-flatten:

```
List(List(1),List(2),List(3)).fold(Nil)( (x,y) => y ::: x )
```

Second, if you're creating a new collection of the same type, it's often easier to use the existing collection to generate an empty one than to try to plug the types in for an empty collection.  It's especially easy if you have pipe defined somewhere:

```
class PipeAnything[A](a: A) { def |>[B](f: A => B) = f(a) }
implicit def anything_can_be_piped[A](a: A) = new PipeAnything(a)

List(1,2,3) |> { x => x.foldLeft(x.take(0))( (y,z) => z :: y ) }
```

Finally, don't forget that you can define your own methods pretty easily that can do something consistent with your types, even if you have to use a bit of trickery to get it to work:

```
def foldMe[A,B](example: A, list: List[B])(f: (List[A],B) => List[A]) = {
  (List(example).take(0) /: list)(f)
}

scala> foldMe( ("",0), List("fish","wish","dish") )( (x,y) => (y.take(1), y.length) :: x )
res40: List[(java.lang.String, Int)] = List((d,4), (w,4), (f,4))
```

Here, note that the example is *not a zero*, but rather is only used as an exemplar of the thing with the type that you want.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers, given that I can't accept both I will accept one and upvote the other.