# Convincing scala compiler that Nil has the right type

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming

So I've got my version of List class in scala:

```
sealed trait List[+A] {
  (...)
}

case object Nil extends List[Nothing] 
case class Cons[+A](_head: A, _tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

now I'm trying to write `reverse` in terms of my `foldLeft` which is the following:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def foldLeft[A,B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = l match {
        case Nil => z
        case Cons(x,xs) => foldLeft(xs,f(z,x))(f)
}
```

here is the problematic part:

```
def revers[A](l:List[A]) : List[A] = foldLeft(l,Nil)((b,a) => Cons(a,b))
```

that gives me type errors:

```
[error]  found   : datastructures.Cons[A]
[error]  required: datastructures.Nil.type
[error]         foldLeft(l,Nil)((b,a) => Cons(a,b))
```

I've could solve this by not using Nil at all like this:

```
def revers[A](l:List[A]) : List[A] = l match {
            case Nil => Nil
            case Cons(x,xs) => foldLeft(xs,Cons(x,Nil))((b,a) => Cons(a,b))
}
```

but still I would like to know how can I pass this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the type :

```
scala> def revers[A](l:List[A]) : List[A] = 
               foldLeft(l,Nil:List[A])((b,a) => Cons(a,b))
revers: [A](l: List[A])List[A]

scala> val l:List[Int] = Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil)))
l: List[Int] = Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil)))

scala> revers(l)
res0: List[Int] = Cons(3,Cons(2,Cons(1,Nil)))
```

Scala's type inference works one block at a time, so when you write foldLeft(l,Nil), it expects the return type to be Nil. The function you passed ((b,a) => Cons(a,b))) has a return type of Cons[A], leading to the error. Specifying that Nil:List[A] in foldLeft(l, Nil) prevents it. See stackoverflow.com/questions/9785655/… for better explanations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you explain, why the compiler is complaining? Since Nil is extension of List[Nothing] with List having covariant type constructor I thought that everything should be ok out of the box? If I remember Nothing is a subtype of everything in scala so in particular any 'A' that would be substituted?

Comment: Scala's type inference works one block at a time, so when you write `foldLeft(l,Nil)`, it expects the return type to be `Nil`. The function you passed (`(b,a) => Cons(a,b))`) has a return type of `Cons[A]`, leading to the error. Specifying that `Nil:List[A]` in `foldLeft(l, Nil)` prevents it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785655/why-doesnt-passing-nil-to-foldleft-work for better explanations.

Comment: Thans again for answering and pointing me in the right direction.